# How to fix form action issue in XHTML 1.0 Strict

Tags: javascript, css, validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

I've got an issue with validating my code to XHTML 1.0 Strict.

I've been using the [w.3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) to try and validate my page.
It tells me

> Line 112, Column 24: required attribute "action" not specified

```
        <form id="orderform">
```

> The attribute given above is required for an element that you've used,
>   but you have omitted it. For instance, in most HTML and XHTML document
>   types the "type" attribute is required on the "script" element and the
>   "alt" attribute is required for the "img" element.
>
> Typical values for type are type="text/css" for and
>   type="text/javascript" for script.

I'm relatively new to XHMTL and CSS and I'm also learning Javascript at this time, I've done a Google search and I've found a lot of people talking about using a Javascript line to fix the error, but none of them are clear enough. Is there anyone here who can provide a clear explanation for me?

This is my XHTML  code..

```
    <form id="orderform">
<div class="field">
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    # of Home shirts:
    <input type="text" id="homeshirt" name="home" value="" onchange="updateOrder();" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    # of Away shirts:
    <input type="text" id="awayshirt" name="away" value="" onchange="updateOrder();" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    Date of collection:
    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    Subtotal:
    <input type="text" id="subtotal" name="subtotal" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    Tax:
    <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    Total:
    <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div id="button">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Place Order" onclick="placeOrder(this.form);" />
</div>
</form>
```

and my Javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateOrder() {
            const TAXRATE = 0.0925;
            const SHIRTPRICE = 39.99;
            var numHomeShirt = parseInt(document.getElementById("homeshirt").value);
            var numAwayShirt = parseInt(document.getElementById("awayshirt").value);
            if (isNaN(numHomeShirt))
                numHomeShirt = 0;
            if (isNaN(numAwayShirt))
                numAwayShirt = 0;
            var subTotal = (numHomeShirt + numAwayShirt) * SHIRTPRICE;
            var tax = subTotal * TAXRATE;
            var total = subTotal + tax;
            document.getElementById("subtotal").value = "£" + subTotal.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("tax").value = "£" + tax.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("total").value = "£" + total.toFixed(2);
        }

        function placeOrder(form) {
            if (document.getElementById("name").value == "")
                alert("I'm sorry but you need to provide a name to print on the shirt.");

            else if (document.getElementById("date").value == "")
                alert ("I'm sorry but you must provide a date you can collect your shirt(s).");

        }
    </script>
```

Thank you for your time,

Cheers.
Jamie

Comment: What about just adding empty action? `<form id="orderform" action="">`

Comment: Yes. Adding a `action=""` will do it. Also, a small note. When running this validator, the "program" does not execute any Javascript on your place, hence, a js workaround for this will not work.

Comment: Thank you guys, the empty action has now allowed for my page to validate, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're new to web development, you may want to [beware of XHTML](http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml) because, from the perspective of almost-2012, it was basically a failed experiment. Not everybody thinks so, of course, so you should do your own research.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too obvious and I'm missing something, but why not just add the action attribute to the form?

Answer (score 1):

No need for javascript. If you're using php just add the following code:

```
<form id="your_id" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Basically, this code will set the action to the same page.

Or others suggest, just add an empty action :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix that particular validation error you need to include the action attribute in the form element.

```
<form id="orderform" action="">
```

It looks like you're using JavaScript to handle form submission, so you should just be able to leave the action empty, otherwise give it a value that pertains to the form submission php script.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML require that your form include an action that will be called (that is, another script on the server) when the submit button is pressed.

Currently you're only implementing the behaviour in Javascript - if this is disabled then nothing will happen.  Ideally you should point to a script, usually the same PHP script as the one generating the form, to handle the submit button press:

```
<form id="your_id" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
```

Then your script should handle the submission in the case that the Javascript didn't.